# Equation with $x$ and $\exp(x)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis

Let consider the equation:
$$e^{0.075x} - 1 = 0.09x$$

I set: $f(x) = e^{0.075x}-1$ and $g(x) = 0.09x$, the I find the cut points of two curves $f$ and $g$. But Is there any way to solve this equation? Thanks you for any help.

Comment: This equation can only be solved numerically.

Comment: Does it has to be in an analytic way?

Comment: The solution can be expressed in terms of the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Answer (score 2):

As Lucian commented the solution of $$a e^{b x}+c=d x$$ can be expressed in terms of the Lambert W function (this is a fascinating function; I suggest you go to the Wikipedia paga Lucian mentionned).

The general solution is given by $$x=\frac{c}{d}-\frac{1}{b}\,W(-z)$$ where $$z=\frac{a b }{d}e^{\frac{b c}{d}}$$ For your specific case, $a=1,b=0.075,c=-1,d=0.09$, beside the trivial solution $x=0$, the solution is given by $$x=-\frac{20}{9} \left(5+6\,W_{-1}\left(-\frac{5}{6 e^{5/6}}\right)\right)\approx 4.72266$$

Comment: You are welcome ! I gave you the formula just to satisfy your immediate curiosity. Again, look at Lambert function (Lambert and Euler worked together) : to me, it is one of the most important after $\log(x)$ and $e^x$. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all rewrite the equation in the form:

$e^{\frac 3 {40}x}-{\frac 9 {100}}x=1$

And the solution is clearly $0$ but if instead of $1$ on the right side we had something like $2$ the solution would heve been:

$x=\frac {-200} 9-{40W(\frac 5 6e^{\frac 5 3})\over 3}$